# Wordpress. The template tab of a page doesn't appear

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

In admin panel of Wordpress I have created a new page named "Home". In a theme folder I created file with name "home.php" where wrote "<?php /* * Template name: home */". But in page edit the "template" tab doesn't appear even after hard reload. I have no idea what's the problem. Could anyone help me please?

I tried to do hard reload many times. Tried firstly to create template file and then the page and vise versa

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `home.php` is a reserved template name, please check, you'll see `home.php` as a fallback for front pages and index

[image: Template hierarchy]

Try changing the file name to `template-home.php`or something different, that should work

Comment: I've changed the name but unfortunately no changes. What else it can be?

Comment: If you're using WordPress 6.1 or newer the Page Template is now displayed on the Summary metabox, under the URL, please check if it's there